# Loop through continuous form records and adding them to a table

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Good afternoon,

I have a bound continuous form with a yes/no checkbox for each of the records shown. I'd like to have my users be able to click a "Select all" control and automatically have each one of those records be added to a *different* table.

So far, I have my loop working but not quite sure where to insert the proper code to add the records. I am using a frame control with a with a "Select all" "Deselect all" options. The [PrintPart] is the Yes/No field in the form.

Many thanks.

```
Private Sub SelectionFrame_Click()
    
    Dim SQL as String
    
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    
    SQL = "INSERT INTO PARTS_T ([PRINTORDER], [PART_TITLE], [PARTID]) 
      VALUES (" & Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount + 1 & "," & Chr(34) & 
      Me.PART_TITLE & Chr(34) & "," & Me.PARTID & ");"

    'Toggle select/deselect all
    Select Case Me.SelectionFrame
        Case 1 'Select
             With Me.RecordsetClone
            .MoveFirst
                Do While Not .EOF
                    .Edit
                    !PrintPart = True
                     RunSQLCode
                    .Update
                    .MoveNext
                Loop
            End With
        Case 2 'Deselect
            With Me.RecordsetClone
            .MoveFirst
                Do While Not .EOF
                    .Edit
                    !PrintPart = False
                    .Update
                    .MoveNext
                Loop
            End With
    End Select
        
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occurred: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & "Error Description: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error - " & APPNAME
    
End Sub
```

Comment: If users (or code) are checking a checkbox control bound to field to select records for copying, multiple simultaneous users will conflict. This is a common question/issue.

Comment: Thank you June 7. This database will not be for multi-user use. I it take by your comment that there is no solution?

Comment: For a single user, solution should be simple. Use an INSERT SELECT action SQL. Looping is not necessary to set all records as checked or unchecked - just run an UPDATE action SQL. What other filter criteria is applied to form?

Comment: Thanks again June7. I thought about and tried placing an INSERT statement and placed it after the boolean value of the PrintPart line and got the first record to stick but not the rest. It essentially entered the first record 7 times (the number of records in the form currently).

Comment: Edit question to show attempted INSERT code. So do you want to copy entire record or just record ID? Latter is probably best.

Comment: Thanks June7, posted.

Comment: SQL string is referencing controls on form so of course same values are used in the loop. If you want to add record referencing the RecordsetClone data, SQL must be built within the loop and reference RecordsetClone fields, not the form. Asking again, any other filter criteria applied to form? And why copying data to another table anyway?

Comment: Sorry about that. No, no filters.

Comment: As far as why copying data to another table, it is just the way the DB is set up. No special reason.

Comment: Then why not simplify db and your life and just use a filtered query for whatever this other table is used for?

Comment: Sorry. About entire record or just ID - I'd go with whatever works best. Thank you.

Comment: The DB has been in the making for a while so simplifying it does not really sound appealing quite honestly. I'll try to see how I can make it work with a query. Thanks again June7.

Comment: Using a query is simplifying. Otherwise, I already pointed out how to simplify procedure that saves data to another table. Looping a RecordsetClone is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run repeated SQL. DAO is way simpler and faster:

```vb
Private Sub SelectionFrame_Click()
    
    Dim Source      As DAO.Recordset 
    Dim Target      As DAO.Recordset
    Dim SQL         As String 
    Dim PrintPart   As Boolean
    Dim PrintOrder  As Long
    
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    
    Set Source = Me.RecordsetClone
    PrintOrder = Source.RecordCount 
    If PrintOrder > 0 Then
        SQL = "Select * From PARTS_T"
        Set Target = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
        PrintPart = Me.SelectionFrame
        Source.MoveFirst
        While Not Source.EOF
            If Source!PrintPart.Value <> PrintPart Then
                Source.Edit
                    Source!PrintPart.Value = PrintPart
                Source.Update
            End If
            Target.AddNew
                Target!PRINTORDER.Value = PrintOrder + 1
                Target!PART_TITLE.Value = Source!PART_TITLE.Value
                Target!PARTID.Value = Source!PARTID.Value
            Target.Update
        Wend
        Target.Close
    End If        
    Source.Close

    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occurred: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & "Error Description: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error - " & APPNAME
    
End Sub
```

Comment: **Thank you so much Gustav** I will give this a whirl and report back. I appreciate you taking the time to throw this sample code together, much appreciated!

Comment: I couldn't get it to work @Gustav but I certainly appreciate your answer. Many thanks.

Comment: _I couldn't get it to work_ .... doesn't tell much. Remove the error handler.

Comment: I apologize Gustav. Wasn't trying to be cryptic. Rather than posting what failed, I decided to give @June7 post of using an INSERT INTO SELECT Statement a try and I got it working correctly. Thanks again for being willing to help Gustav, much appreciated. :-)